# Meteor 'Cannot find module 'crypto'

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor, package.json

I keep getting an error saying "Cannot find module 'crypto'" I am using meteor and from my understanding, npm recently made crypto deprecated and made it built in however, my site now crashes. As a final issue, I cannot revert because I have not installed the module on my computer and it is no longer available on npmjs.org (I believe).

I have tried: updating meteor and npm, reinstalling the package, meteor reset, running an npm install.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove _crypto_ dependency from your package.json.

Comment: I'd like to add on @TGrif that you try to completely remove the node modules by running `rm -rf node_modules/` and installing new packages with `meteor npm install` prepending `meteor` before npm to install things with meteor node version.

Comment: Thanks, removing the dependency worked